# Is Domain-Driven Design still valid right now?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, models

We want to implement a model or guideline for our OO designs,. We like Domain-Driven Design. Our specific question is: do you think DDD is still valid right now beyond the pattern design?  If so, do other approaches or variants exist that we should evaluate ?

Fundamentally we develop enterprise web and desktop applications using Visual studio (c#).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, DDD is as pertinent today as ever. The idea that one should strive for an Ubiquitous Language, such that the domain in code is not divorced from the domain as described by the domain experts, will probably remain a good idea for a long time, and it is easier today to focus on the domain first and consider persistence as a "secondary" problem than it used to be. It is also still true that DDD requires an important design effort, and its value is going to be proportional to how complex the domain is.

I have not written any application using the methodology, but I have been reading a lot on Event Sourcing and CQRS lately, and they both seems like a very interesting approach which should fit well with DDD (and are usually advocated by people who are DDD proponents).

<s>I can't find it right now, but there is a video interviews of Eric Evans floating around somewhere on the web,</s>You may be interested in watching [this video of Eric Evans](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ddd-eric-evans), which is a form of retrospective on the methodology a few years after writing the book, and what he would have done differently now.

Comment: I think this is the video link you referenced: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ddd-eric-evans

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it - for some reason my Google-fu was betraying me earlier, will add it in the answer itself.

Comment: We're really looking for a methodology that allows us to offer our customers guarantee their investment not only in terms of usability and stability if it is not efficiently maintainable. I think DDD fits very well in this aspect, It seems that one key is to determine which projects DDD can to add value and apply it there, even to apply only in the most complex areas of the projects  may be another alternative.

Comment: Another key point is how avoid disconections between the model (like common and general ubiquitous languaje) and the code,  would also have to see how much can engage non-technical staff with this way of communication and if we would have to face a learning curve with its obvious overhead.
I think,  It would be very interesting to evaluate such DDD-Agile can be combined.
I found some interesting points here:   http://deepfriedbytes.com/search/?q=episode+6
and here: (http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice)

Comment: You may also be interested in this recent post on Event Sourcing as a strategic advantage: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/10/11/event-sourcing-as-a-strategic-advantage/

Answer (score 2):

I think DDD is quite alive (or quite as dead) as before. My opinion is that the "domain" is a hot topic today because of DSLs (Domain-Specific Languages) and MDE (Model-Driven Engineering).

You may want to learn more about a similar "domain-driven" aproach, called DSM - Domain-Specific modeling. In DSM, you can work through patterns but you also define code generators that translate your domain-specific design into working code.

Check the [DSM Forum](http://www.dsmforum.org/) or Wikipedia for more information about DSM.

The two most notable tools right now in this area are [MetaEdit+](http://www.metacase.com/) from MetaCase and [AtomWeaver](http://www.atomweaver.com) from Isomeris.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted -- +1 to even it out.

Comment: @david Thanks. I guess it was because my comment about DDD (first paragraph) was added after the downvote...